# How to display a list of shell objects?

Tags: winapi, atl, windows-shell

I want to display an aggregate of shell items inside my List View control, gathered from different folders, *similar to how Explorer's file search mechanism works*.

I have a feeling I need to use [`IShellFolderView::AddObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774969.aspx), but the entire interface is deprecated, and either way, I can't figure out how to actually get this to work.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you insist on "getting" shell objects, I assume you are not using a list view control which require you to write your own shell support like the CMFCShellListCtrl does. It would be pretty trivial to add multiple folder support if you already wrote the code to display files from a single folder in a list view control.

If you are using the Explorer Browser control, check [the Hilo project sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff708696%28v=MSDN.10%29.aspx), it creates a search folder with a scope of the aggregation of the user's libraries. You can probably create your own folder collection by using the IObjectCollection interface of the CLSID_EnumerableObjectCollection object. For a sample of displaying a search folder in the Explorer Browser control, check the [Explorer Browser Search Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940358%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If it's your listview control, then you can just ListView_InsertItem each one. Enumerate the objects from wherever you want and add them to your listview.

Comment: Then they're no longer shell objects. E.g. right-click doesn't work, drag-drop doesn't work, change detection doesn't work, et cetera, et cetera...

Comment: That's for you to hook up. If you want to manage your own listview, then you are responsible for managing the interface. If you want somebody else to manage the interface, then use an ExplorerBrowser control. I assumed you already had a working listview where the items came from a single folder, and you wanted to extend it to multiple folders. Sorry for the misunderstanding.